# OutOfMemoryException in WebCrawler

Tags: c#, exception, out-of-memory

So I need to save several links from a site, but when it reaches near the 64k links it gives me the error `OutOfMemoryException`.

Here is my code, please if someone could help me it would be wonderful.

Note : if you want to test (of course you have to edit to test, but it is not that much to edit), the url it receives is :

```
http://santacatarina.entrei.net/busca/listar_empresas.php?filter={0}&pagina={1}
```

The code :

```
namespace WebCrawler.SantaCatarina
{

class SCLinkFinder : ILinkFinder

{

private readonly Queue<char> _alfabeto;
private int _paginaAtual;
private char _letraAtual;

public SCLinkFinder()
{
    _alfabeto = new Queue<char>();
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('1');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('A');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('B');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('C');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('D');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('E');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('F');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('G');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('H');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('I');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('J');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('K');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('L');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('M');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('N');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('O');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('P');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('Q');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('R');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('S');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('T');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('U');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('V');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('W');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('X');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('Y');
    _alfabeto.Enqueue('Z');

    _paginaAtual = 1;
    _letraAtual = _alfabeto.Dequeue();
}

public string[] Find(string url)
{
    List<string> _empresas = new List<string>();

    if (!_alfabeto.Any() && _letraAtual == ' ')
    {
        return _empresas.ToArray();
    }
    var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
    var formattedUrl = String.Format(url, _letraAtual, _paginaAtual++);
    var document = webGet.Load(formattedUrl);
    var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='conteudo']/div[@class='gratuito']/p/a");

    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        var href = node.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
        _empresas.Add(href);
    }

    var elUrlProximaPagina = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='principal']/div[@id='conteudo']/div[@class='paginacao']/a[contains(@class,'nextPage')]");
    if (elUrlProximaPagina == null)
    {
        _letraAtual = _alfabeto.Any() ? _alfabeto.Dequeue() : ' ';
        _paginaAtual = 1;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(_letraAtual);
    Console.WriteLine(_paginaAtual);

    DadoPo.SalvarUrl();         

    return Find(url);
}
```

}

Ok, now the error is at another place, it is giving outofmemoryexception at 
var document = webGet.Load(formattedUrl);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persist the content of _empresas in the harddisk (database, physical file) after N times(1,000 for example) of scraped information from the website. And then clean the _empresas for a new set of information

What you are doing is pretty much using all the memory allowed by CLR for your PE

```
namespace WebCrawler.SantaCatarina
{
class SCLinkFinder : ILinkFinder
{
    private readonly Queue<char> _alfabeto;

    private int _paginaAtual;
    private char _letraAtual;

    public SCLinkFinder()
    {
        _alfabeto = new Queue<char>();
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('1');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('A');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('B');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('C');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('D');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('E');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('F');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('G');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('H');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('I');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('J');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('K');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('L');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('M');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('N');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('O');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('P');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('Q');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('R');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('S');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('T');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('U');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('V');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('W');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('X');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('Y');
        _alfabeto.Enqueue('Z');

        _paginaAtual = 1;
        _letraAtual = _alfabeto.Dequeue();
    }

    public string[] Find(string url)
    {
        List<string> _empresas = new List<string>();

        if (!_alfabeto.Any() && _letraAtual == ' ')
        {
            return _empresas.ToArray();
        }
        var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
        var formattedUrl = String.Format(url, _letraAtual, _paginaAtual++);
        var document = webGet.Load(formattedUrl);
        var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='conteudo']/div[@class='gratuito']/p/a");

        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            var href = node.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
            _empresas.Add(href);
        }

        var elUrlProximaPagina = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='principal']/div[@id='conteudo']/div[@class='paginacao']/a[contains(@class,'nextPage')]");
        if (elUrlProximaPagina == null)
        {
            _letraAtual = _alfabeto.Any() ? _alfabeto.Dequeue() : ' ';
            _paginaAtual = 1;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(_letraAtual);
        Console.WriteLine(_paginaAtual);

        //Your code to read _empresas and Persist in database(or file)            

        return Find(url);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: could you explain better please? Maybe with an example.|
Maybe just doing like this :
if (_empresas == 30000){
    for (int i = 0; i < _empresas; i++){
     Database.Link = _empresas
    }
_empresas.empty;
}
? Or I misunderstood?

Comment: See the change above, I just changed the _empresas to be instanced inside the method, and in the end, before the return, saves in the database or append in a txt/xml file. You should stop getting out of memory exception

Comment: but most important, understand why you are getting exception, doing this way above, you allow the garbage collector to clean the memory for you

Comment: Thank you! But shouldn't I empty the _empresas or it will not  effect?

Comment: you don't have to, since a new _empresas instance is created everytime the recursive method is called